# SVN post-commit hook sending a message back to client

Tags: svn, bash, stderr, post-commit-hook

I'm writing a post-commit script in bash, and I'd like to pass messages back to the client who's making a commit.  However

```
echo my message >&2
```

isn't making it back to the client.  Is it even possible to send messages back with a post-commit hook?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Condering a [post-commit hook](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.reposhooks.post-commit.html) does:

> anything that the hook printed to stderr will be marshalled back to the client, making it easier to diagnose hook failures.

you can check if this isn't a simple quote issue:

```
echo "my message" >&2
```

You can see in those [hook examples](http://projects.puppetlabs.com/projects/1/wiki/Puppet_Version_Control) that any `echo` to `>&2` includes quotes.

The [bash chapter on redirection](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html) also includes examples with quotes.

However, as [pmod](https://stackoverflow.com/users/356838/pmod) details in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8427369/6309), that stderr message won't be visible unless the exit status of the script differs from 0, as illustrated in "[subversion post-commit hook: print an error message that the user can see?](https://serverfault.com/a/386219/783)"

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "test" >&2
exit 1
```

Comment: As pmod says below, the stderr screen is only printed to the client if this (or any) hook returns a nonzero return value. That was probably the issue @CamelBlues encountered.

Comment: This answer is wrong. Pmod has it right that the script must return a non 0 value.

Answer (score 14):

Hook will show STDERR only if it fails (and as you may now, hook doesn't display STDOUT). 
Thus, you have to return non-zero code from your script to pass "my message" to user (just add **exit 1** after echo).

Take a look [here](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.ref.reposhooks.post-commit.html):

> If the post-commit hook returns a nonzero exit status, the commit will
>   not be aborted since it has already completed. However, anything that
>   the hook printed to stderr will be marshalled back to the client,
>   making it easier to diagnose hook failures.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem, with Apache and mod_svn. It turned out that the marshalling fails when the text being marshalled contained `&`, `<` or `>` characters. After substituting them with `&amp;`, `&lt;` and `&gt;` the text got through.

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what we were facing with mod_svn.  Never would've figured it out...